# How can I define a metric in xAct?

Tags: physics, xact

I'm using "xAct" package and I want to define a my metric, that is a non standard metric. For example, my metric is diagonal

```
 g={-e^(2a),e^(2b),e^(2b),e^(2b),e^(2c),e^(2c)sin^2(theta)},
```

where a,b,c are functions of the time variable t. I cannot understand how I can insert this definition when I use the command DefMetric...Can anyone help me?

Comment: have you looked at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67446/perturbation-theory-in-general-relativity-using-xact  (see search button top right)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Yes, I've looked, but the problem is that I have a manifold in 6D and at a certain point Mathematica finds errors, even if I execute standard metric! Is there (or Do you know) a more simple package than xAct that calculates Riemann and Ricci tensors and the Gauss Bonnet term?

Answer (score 8):

First of all, note that you'll need to use `xCoba` to do any calculations in terms of coordinate components.  From the [xTensor documentation page:](http://xact.es/xTensor/index.html)

> *xTensor* does not perform component calculations. Use the companion package *xCoba*.

In `xCoba`, you need to define a "chart" on your manifold with the coordinates you're using, and explicitly call `DefScalarFunction` for the functions you're going to be using.  For example, here's how you'd define a flat FRW metric:

```
<< xAct`xCoba`
(* Define the manifold *)
DefManifold[M, 4, IndexRange[a, n]]

(* Define coordinates on a chart of M *)
DefChart[ch, M, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {t[], x[], y[], z[]}, ChartColor -> Blue]

(* Define aa (the scale factor) to be a scalar function of one or more coordinates *)
DefScalarFunction[aa]

(* Create the metric tensor in terms of its coordinate components *) 
met = CTensor[DiagonalMatrix[{-1, aa[t[]]^2, aa[t[]]^2, aa[t[]]^2}], {-ch, -ch}];

(* Set this metric to be the metric of the manifold on the chart ch *)
SetCMetric[met, ch, SignatureOfMetric -> {3, 1, 0}]

(* Define the covariant derivative operator *)
cd = CovDOfMetric[met];

(* Calculate various curvature tensors and cache *)
MetricCompute[met, ch, All]

(* Display Kretschmann invariant *)
Kretschmann[cd][]

Out[] = (12 (aa'[t[]]^4 + aa[t[]]^2 (aa'')[t[]]^2))/aa[t[]]^4
```

The Gauss-Bonnet invariant is not automatically computed by `MetricCompute`, but you could easily define it in terms of the appropriate contractions.

Note that none of this is terribly clear in the main `xCobaDoc.nb` file that's linked to on the [main xCoba page.](http://www.xact.es/xCoba/index.html)  However, when you download and install the package, there should be a file called `xCobaDoc2.nb` in the Documentation directory that gives a lot more detail on how to use `CTensor` to define coordinate tensors, with some helpful examples.  That's how I personally figured out how to use the package...

Comment: what is the {-ch,-ch} for in the met=CTensor[...] part?

Comment: @jboy:  It signifies that you're giving the metric components in terms of the `ch` coordinates.  The `-` signs signify that you're providing the components of $g_{\mu \nu}$ in this basis;  if you wanted to provide $g^{\mu \nu}$, you would use `{ch, ch}` instead.

Comment: thanks for that. How about this line SetCMetric[met, ch, SignatureOfMetric -> {3, 1, 0}] what does {3,1,0} mean? isnt the signature for the robertson-walker metric -1,1,1,1?

Comment: @jboy:  The order of elements in that list is "numbers of +s", "number of -s", "number of 0s".

Answer (score 3):

`MetricInBasis[metric,-B,yourmetric]` can work.
See "Spherical Symmetry" of xCoba examples for more information.